# Maven not using Central Repository

Tags: maven

When I try to import anything using Maven, it always only search in local or REDHAT repository but never in Central Repository.

What should I change so that I can use Maven Central Repository?

Thanks,
Swaraj

Answer (score 1):

See:

- [Maven, POM Reference, Repositories](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Repositories)
- [Maven, Introduction to Repositories](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-repositories.html)
- [Maven, Settings Reference, Servers](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Servers)